# Filling Various Text views with variables

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-text

I'm writing my first Swift app and I am looking for some guidance on how best to fill my Text view elements with variables.

Below, I have a simplified version of my app's main ContentView- in reality, it has about 100 Text view elements.
I need to change the Text's title to the values Variable1, Variable2, Variable3 and Variable4. With 100 Text view elements, I would have to
modify each Text view element to define and use Variable1, Variable 2,......Variable100 (a lot of typing and hard to edit!)

```
struct TenView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("Group100")
                    Text("One")
                    Text("Two")
                    Text(Variable1)
                        .background(Color.yellow)
                    Text("Four")
                    Text("Five")
                    Text("Six")
                }
                VStack {
                    Text("Group200")
                    Text("One")
                    Text("Two")
                    Text("Three")
                    Text("Four")
                    Text(Variable2)
                        .background(Color.yellow)
                    Text("Six")
                }
                VStack {
                    Text("Group300")
                    Text("One")
                    Text(Variable3)
                        .background(Color.yellow)
                    Text("Three")
                    Text("Four")
                    Text("Five")
                    Text(Variable4)
                        .background(Color.yellow)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Are there better ways to achieve this?

Should I put the 100 Variables into an array and do something like:

```
myArray: String= ["","Alpha", "Bravo",....."100Zulu"]
VStack {
    Text("Group100")
    Text("One")
    Text("Two")
    Text(myArray[1])
        .background(Color.yellow)
    Text("Four")
    Text("Five")
    Text("Six")
}
VStack {
    Text("Group200")
    Text("One")
    Text("Two")
    Text("Three")
    Text("Four")
    Text("myArray[2]")
        .background(Color.yellow)
    Text("Six")
}
```

Or is there some way of using a forEach with some logic?

```
VStack {
myArray.forEach {  but only in specific Text views
        Text($0)
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you do the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/  without knowing the **very basics** you will struggle coding your App. Look for info on `ForEach`.

Comment: I've done a lot of reading/tutorials. I understand dynamic lists and using foreach. The question I have is how to stipulate which Text views receive the data, in a non-sequential layout? I don't think I can  iterate through my array and create Texts since I only have specific views which need to be populated.

Comment: read my comment again, "...Look for info on `ForEach`", not `forEach`, there is a big difference.

Comment: The UUID was the key piece I was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, where you setup your data structure as shown in `Item`.
Use these items in a list `ForEach` loop. Use some very simple logic
to display your data the way you want it. Adjust the example code to suit your particular needs.

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let index: Int
    let value: String
    let group: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let myData = [Item(index: 1, value: "Alpha", group: "Group100"),
                  Item(index: 2, value: "Bravo", group: "Group100"),
                  Item(index: 3, value: "100Zulu", group: "Group200"),
                  Item(index: 1, value: "200Zulu", group: "Group300"),
                  Item(index: 4, value: "300Zulu", group: "Grou400")]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(myData) { item in
                VStack {
                    Text(item.group)
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(1..<7, id: \.self) { ndx in
                            if item.index == ndx {
                                Text(item.value).background(Color.yellow)
                            } else {
                                Text("\(ndx)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```